# Find Line of Code Which Doctrine Produced specific Query

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In MySQL Slow query log I found a query that should be optimized. All queries are generated by Doctrine. But the project has a lot of files, and I don't know where can I find the line of doctrine code that generate this query.

Is  there any solution to find where query produced by doctrine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution but some general advice. If you have access to the site in debug mode, open the Symfony profiler and look at the Performance tab. You will see a waterfall chart of the time the application spend processing the tasks. The doctrine queries are shown in orange, and if you know roughly where in the total number of queries you are looking for you can glean some information.

For example if the particular query is the fifth query to run (you can find this in the doctrine tab) you can use the profiler to see when the query is roughly running. In this example the first query is the user lookup query checking login status (notice that it runs before my controller even runs).

[image]

If I called database queries in my twig files, the doctrine query would show in the time line about the green lines on the bottom. Then I would know to look in the twig files for the query.

Just a few suggestions to help you find the queries.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't advise you to edit what you want to edit.

Each time you generate an entity, Symfony generate an repository as well. (src/AppBundle/Repository)
It's within the reposity that you will create your custom functions and query.

As for DQL examples, there are a bunch here on SO... ;)